# Overriding methods map and flatMap in class extending trait Iterator

Tags: scala, inheritance, collections, iterator-traits

As a Scala beginner I'm trying to implement a counter for every item of an `Iterator` being retrieved and processed in a `for` expression as well as a counter incremented every time a new iteration over one of the "loops" of the expression (outer loop and nested loops) is started. The requirement is to accomplish this without simply placing a statement like `counter = counter + 1` at numerous locations in the `for` expression.
The following listing shows my proposed solution to this problem and I would like to know, why method `next` implementing `Iterator`'s abstract member gets called (and the corresponding counter is incremented) whereas `flatMap` and `map` overriding their pendants defined in trait `Iterator` (and calling them via `super`) are not called at all.

```
object ZebraPuzzle {
  var starts = 0
  var items = 0

  class InstrumentedIter[A](it: Iterator[A]) extends Iterator[A] {
    private val iterator = it

    def hasNext = it.hasNext

    def next() = {
      items = items + 1
      it.next()
    }

    override def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): Iterator[B] = {
      starts = starts + 1
      super.flatMap(f)
    }

    override def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Iterator[B] = {
      starts = starts + 1
      super.map(f)
    }
  } // inner class InstrumentedIter
```

The corresponding `for` expression looks like this:

```
  def solve = {
    val first = 1
    val middle = 3
    val houses = List(first, 2, middle, 4, 5)
    for {
      List(r, g, i, y, b) <-  new InstrumentedIter(houses.permutations)
      if ...
      List(eng, span, ukr, jap, nor) <- new InstrumentedIter(houses.permutations)
      if ...
      if ...
      if ...
      List(of, tea, milk, oj, wat) <- new InstrumentedIter(houses.permutations)
      if ...
      ...
    } yield ...
  ...
  }
...
} // standalone singleton object ZebraPuzzle
```

I would be grateful if someone could give me a hint how to solve the given problem in a better way. But most of all I am interested to know why my solution overriding `Iterator`'s `map` and `flatMap` doesn't work like expected by my somewhat limited brain ;-)

Regards

Martin

Comment: Please write code that can be compiled and run by others. I have no interest in giving answers to questions where I first have to think several minutes what the given code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I managed to find the answer myself. The problem with my solution is that withFilter returns a reference to a newly created AbstractIterator, not an InstrumentedIterator. As a possible solution this reference can be passed to the constructor of a wrapper class like  InstrumentedIterator that mixes in trait Iterator and overrides methods map and flatMap. These methods can then do the counting ...

Regards
Martin

Answer (score -1):

Your lines

```
List(...) <- Iterator
```

don't call map and flatmap. They call unapply in the List companion object which unpacks Iterators into tuples.

To call map or flatMap you need something like

```
item <- Iterator
```

You need to either define a companion object for InstrumentedIter with an unapply method or use the map/flatMap syntax in your for comprehension.